# MATLAB code for mapping two vectors with equal distribution

Tags: python, matlab, vector

I have a python code that I'm trying to port to MATLAB.

The code does the following:

Suppose I have two lists A = [0,1,2,3,4] and B = [0,1,2]. It creates an association matrix M of size 5x3 with having element 1 if there is an association between A and B and 0 otherwise. The caveat is that A must be equally distributed among B (as far as possible). For example, B[0] and B[1] can be associated with 2 distinct elements each from A, and B[2] is associated with the last element. The association should be random. Further, an element from A cannot be mapped to only one element of B.

In python I achieved this by

```py
S = len(A)
V = len(B)
random.shuffle(A)
assoc = {v: A[v::V] for v in range(V)}
M = {(s, v): 1 if s in assoc[v] else 0 for s in range(S) for v in range(V)}
```

How to achieve this in MATLAB? I don't really need the intermediate assoc. All I'm interested in is the matrix M.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it using integer programming. This is how it goes.

Let x_ij be a binary variable to denote mapping from list A to list B.
So load on an element in list B is L_j = sum_i x_ij. Let z = max_j L_j. We want to minimize this.

Constraint is that one element in list A cannot map to more than one in list B.
Thus, sum_j x_ij = 1.

This is implemented in MATLAB using the optimization toolbox as:

```
assignprob = optimproblem;
x = optimvar('x', numel(A), numel(B), 'Type', 'integer', ...
    'LowerBound', 0, 'UpperBound', 1);
z = optimvar('z', 'LowerBound', 0);

cons1 = sum(x, 2) == 1;
loads = sum(x, 1);
cons2 = z >= loads;

assignprob.Objective = z;
assignprob.Constraints.cons1 = cons1;
assignprob.Constraints.cons2 = cons2;

[sol, fval] = solve(assignprob);
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works.